# Install database without automated schema

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, schema, windows-server-2012-r2

I don't really know where this question should go so I've added all that I feel apply.

I have SQL Server 2016 installed on WS 2012 with IIS.
Create an empty database (No tables) and a SQL user and password.
I host a site in IIS built with ASP .Net and go to its admin webpage. This consists of selecting the database I created above.
Everything runs successfully.

The problem I am coming across is each table adds a schema in the format "IIS AppPool\DatabaseUsername.Tablename" so IIS_AppPool\MyUser.Customers.

I don't know why it does it so I have tried, running the site from the server, from a network PC, adding permissions to Network Service and other accounts but no matter what I do, the database tables all have this schema attached to it. How could I stop it from adding it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the scripts do not schema-qualify object names. In that case, objects created by that user are created in the user's default schema. You can specify the desired default schema for an individual user with T-SQL statement:

```
ALTER USER [IIS AppPool\DatabaseUsername] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
```

Comment: By this you mean when i create the DB run the above statement? Though when i run the entire operation on my local PC i dont get the same issue, so is there something i could do beforehand to avoid it happening and to avoid running the above script each time round?

Comment: How do you create the SQL Server IIS AppPool\DatabaseUsername login?

Comment: Specify the correct schema when you create the table.

Comment: I just create a new user in SSMS, create the DB and then assign permissions for this user to the database. I then run the site via a web browser and when it asks for the user/DB i just enter the user details i created. I dont create the table, the site functionality does this. I will try the above out and will mark as answer if it works. Thx

Comment: In SSMS, specify the default schema for the user on the general page under user properties.